# How to resolve ERROR : #1977 - Cannot convert 'utf8' character 0xD8AD to 'latin1'

Tags: mysql, utf-8, phpmyadmin, sql-update, iso-8859-1

I am working in phpmyadmin where I have Arabic values in name columns like

Ú©Ù„Ø¨ Ø§Ù„Ø±Ù‚ÙŠÙ‘Ø© Ø¹Ù„ÛŒ Ø§Ù„Ø¹Ø²ÛŒØ²Ø¨ÙˆØ±ÛŒï

And I want to convert them to proper form.

I tried these queries and it converted most of the records in the table

```
ALTER DATABASE alfeker_book CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
ALTER TABLE guestbook CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
UPDATE guestbook SET name = CONVERT(BINARY CONVERT(name USING latin1) USING utf8mb4);
```

And also tried

```
UPDATE guestbook SET name = CONVERT(BINARY CONVERT(name USING binary) USING utf8mb4);
```

but few of them remain unchanged and give this error

`#1977 - Cannot convert 'utf8' character 0xD8AD to 'latin1'`

I also tried this query:

```
SELECT id,name, CONVERT(BINARY CONVERT(name USING latin1) USING utf8mb4) AS converted_name FROM guestbook;
```

Which works fine and show the non converted characters perfectly. But when I use the update query it doesn't work.

Comment: `0xD8AD` is `�` (U+D8AD,  *Non Private Use High Surrogate*)…

Answer (score 0):

That's Mojibake or "double encoding" of Arabic text.

There are several ways of fixing the data.  Only one makes it better; the rest make it worse.

Please read [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) and follow the suggestions about getting the HEX of what is in the database, plus `SHOW CREATE TABLE` of the current schema definition.  Also provide `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';` and the connection parameters.

And please back up to before attempting the various `ALTERs` and `CONVERTs`.

With the HEX, I can probably pick the proper conversion.

Comment: `'Ú©Ù„Ø¨ Ø§Ù„Ø±Ù‚ÙŠÙ‘Ø© Ø¹Ù„ÛŒ Ø§Ù„Ø¹Ø²ÛŒØ²Ø¨ÙˆØ±ÛŒ'.encode( 'cp1252').decode('utf-8')` returns `'کلب الرقيّة علی العزیزبوری'` (*example in Python for its universal intelligibility*)…

Comment: I need you to so `SELECT HEX(columnname) FROM ...`